# Is Stackoverflow the only place to get Subsonic support?

Tags: support, stack-overflow, scope

I have an issue still [unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1818915/subsonic-filter-by-xml-column-datatype) but I just thought I'd check how to get support on Subsonic.

I know Rob has previously stated that Stackoverflow is the place to go but I am working on a tight deadline and at the moment I am rather stuck.

I like Subsonic immensely but maybe I shouldn't use it on business type projects because if I get stuck I could be waiting a while!?

Answer (score 2):

The docs for subsonic are located here.

http://www.subsonicproject.com/docs/Main_Page

Personally, I've found subsonic to be pretty self-explanatory once I watched the videos.

Answer (score 1):

ATM- Yes it would seem that way,

http://blog.wekeroad.com/2009/09/08/subsonic-support